# Prove using induction $\ln(n!)\leqslant n\ln(n)$ for $n\geqslant 1$.

Tags: induction

Base case true

$$\ln((n+1)!) = \ln(n+1)+\ln (n!)$$ Product rule
But now I'm suck Idk how to prove that is less than or equal to $(n+1)\ln(n+1)$

Comment: I suggest that you do not skip the preliminaries, even when you post here.  Demonstrate the base case.  And tell us you inductive hypothesis.  At the step you have left off, you are ready to invoke the inductive hypothesis, but where is it?  And, I think that is leaving you wondering what to do next.

Comment: Isn't $$\log(n!)=\log(1)+\log(2)+\ldots+\log(n) \leq \log(n)+\log(n)+\ldots+\log(n)=n\log(n)$$ really trivial?

Answer (score 2):

Note $$\ln((n+1)!) = \ln(n+1)+\ln (n!) \le \ln (n+1)+n\ln n$$

From our inductive hypothesis. But since $\ln n$ is an increasing function, $$\ln((n+1)!) \le \ln (n+1)+n \ln n \le \ln (n+1)+n \ln (n+1)$$

This gives us that $$\ln (n+1)! \le (n+1)\ln n$$

Comment: How you type so fast?!

Comment: @SimpleArt I copy and paste in order to enhance my speed

Comment: Ah... smart....

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** $\ln$ is an increasing function.

Answer (score 0):

"$\ln((n+1)!) = \ln(n+1)+\ln (n!)$"

That's 90% of it.

$\ln(n!) \le n\ln(n)$

so $\ln((n+1)!) = \ln(n+1) + \ln(n!) \le \ln(n+1) + n\ln(n)$.

We need to show $\ln(n+1) + n\ln(n) \le (n+1)\ln(n+1) = \ln(n+1) + n\ln(n+1)$

But $\ln(n+1) + n\ln(n) \le \ln(n+1) + n\ln(n+1)\iff \ln(n) \le \ln(n+1)$.

So if we can show $\ln (n) \le \ln(n+1)$ we are done.  [As as $e > 1$, $\ln(n1) \le \ln(n+1) \iff e^{\ln(n)} = n \le e^{\ln(n+1)} = n+1$]